# How to render a Bounding Box over a rotating Box

Tags: c++, debugging, sfml

Hello Im new to C++ SFML. I would like to ask how I would go about rendering a bounding box over a rotating box. The way I did this was by making another rectangle that was transparent but with outlines and got it to getGlobalBounds of the rotating rectangle but it isn't rendering quite right because I've been using setSize to get the bounding box to grow which means the upper and left portion of the box isnt resizing. I feel like i'm missing something here so Here's my code:

```
sf::RectangleShape Rect[RECT];
sf::RectangleShape AABB[RECT];
Rect[0].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 50.0f));
Rect[1].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 100.0f));
Rect[2].setSize(sf::Vector2f(60.0f, 80.0f));
Rect[3].setSize(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 60.0f));
Rect[4].setSize(sf::Vector2f(30.0f, 250.0f));

AABB[0].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 50.0f));
AABB[1].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 100.0f));
AABB[2].setSize(sf::Vector2f(60.0f, 80.0f));
AABB[3].setSize(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 60.0f));
AABB[4].setSize(sf::Vector2f(30.0f, 250.0f));

for (int x = 0; x < RECT; x++)
{
    //Starting Position
    Rect[x].setOrigin(Rect[x].getSize().x / 2, Rect[x].getSize().y / 2);
    AABB[x].setOrigin(AABB[x].getSize().x / 2, AABB[x].getSize().y / 2);
    xpos += 150;
    Rect[x].setPosition(xpos, ypos);
    AABB[x].setPosition(xpos, ypos);
    colcount++;
    if (colcount == 3)
    {
        xpos = 0;
        ypos += 200;
        colcount = 0;
    }

    Rect[x].setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    AABB[x].setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    AABB[x].setOutlineThickness(1);
}

while (window.isOpen())
{

    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    //Drawing Shapes
    for (int x = 0; x < RECT; x++)
    {
        window.draw(Rect[x]);
        window.draw(AABB[x]);
    }

        Rect[0].rotate(90 * 3.14 / 180);
        Rect[1].rotate(45 * 3.14 / 180);
        Rect[2].rotate(10 * 3.14 / 180);
        Rect[3].rotate(180 * 3.14 / 180);
        Rect[4].rotate(22.5);

    for (int i = 0; i < RECT; i++)
    {
        MinPoint[i].x = Rect[i].getPosition().x - (Rect[i].getSize().x / 2);
        MaxPoint[i].x = Rect[i].getPosition().x + (Rect[i].getSize().x / 2);
        MinPoint[i].y = Rect[i].getPosition().y - (Rect[i].getSize().y / 2);
        MaxPoint[i].y = Rect[i].getPosition().y + (Rect[i].getSize().y / 2);
        AABB[i].setSize(sf::Vector2f(Rect[i].getGlobalBounds().width, Rect[i].getGlobalBounds().height));
    }
```

Comment: Here is an idea, can you get the position of the rotating box corners, or calculate it? if you can, you could calculate the position of the bounding box with them, but the assignment should be done in both elements "at the same time" or you will always see some retard in the movement of one of them...

Comment: sry im a bit of a noob but how could this be done if there was a way to get the corners while rotating

Comment: What I meant, in a very unclear way was that you need to update them both at the same time, sorry I make it more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work. Here's what I did:

```
sf::RectangleShape Rect[RECT];
sf::RectangleShape AABB[RECT];
Rect[0].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 50.0f));
Rect[1].setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 100.0f));
Rect[2].setSize(sf::Vector2f(60.0f, 80.0f));
Rect[3].setSize(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 60.0f));
Rect[4].setSize(sf::Vector2f(30.0f, 250.0f));

for (int x = 0; x < RECT; x++)
{
    //Starting Position
    Rect[x].setOrigin(Rect[x].getSize().x / 2, Rect[x].getSize().y / 2);
    AABB[x].setOrigin(AABB[x].getSize().x / 2, AABB[x].getSize().y / 2);
    xpos += 150;
    Rect[x].setPosition(xpos, ypos);
    AABB[x].setSize(sf::Vector2f(Rect[x].getGlobalBounds().width, Rect[x].getGlobalBounds().height));
    AABB[x].setPosition(Rect[x].getPosition().x, Rect[x].getPosition().y);
    colcount++;
    if (colcount == 3)
    {
        xpos = 0;
        ypos += 200;
        colcount = 0;
    }

    Rect[x].setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    AABB[x].setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    AABB[x].setOutlineThickness(1);
    AABB[x].setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
}

while (window.isOpen())
{

    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    //Drawing Shapes
    for (int x = 0; x < RECT; x++)
    {
        window.draw(Rect[x]);
        window.draw(AABB[x]);
    }

    //Rotation
    Rect[0].rotate(1);
    Rect[1].rotate(45);
    Rect[2].rotate(11.25);
    Rect[3].rotate(5.625);
    Rect[4].rotate(22.5);

    for (int i = 0; i < RECT; i++)
    {
        MinPoint[i].x = AABB[i].getPosition().x - (AABB[i].getSize().x / 2);
        MaxPoint[i].x = AABB[i].getPosition().x + (AABB[i].getSize().x / 2);
        MinPoint[i].y = AABB[i].getPosition().y - (AABB[i].getSize().y / 2);
        MaxPoint[i].y = AABB[i].getPosition().y + (AABB[i].getSize().y / 2);

        AABB[i].setOrigin(AABB[i].getSize().x / 2, AABB[i].getSize().y / 2);
        AABB[i].setSize(sf::Vector2f(Rect[i].getGlobalBounds().width, Rect[i].getGlobalBounds().height));
        AABB[i].setPosition(Rect[i].getPosition().x, Rect[i].getPosition().y);
    }
```